# How to transform search path to actual path in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I used the search feature in windows 7 and selected a folder from the results.
Now if I want to move up the folder hierarchy I can't just use ALT+UP because to folder path is listed as:

> search-ms:displayname=Start%20Menu%20Search%20Results%20in%20Files&crumb=System.StartMenu.Group%3A%3Dfiles&crumb=location:%3A%3A{DF95313-E44D-4AF-BE1B-CACEA2C3065}\Something

And I go back to the search results.

What's the best way to accomplish this task?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the item which folder you want to view, right click the item and select "Open Folder Location".  You can then move up the directory tree as needed.

Comment: That option is not available to me when I right-click.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a new window with "full path" instead of Search Results\"Path", but still have the search window remain intact, DO THIS:

After search results in Win 7, Right click on file and get option Open file location, then press Shift and then click on Open file location and a new window will open with the file highlighted and the search results window will also remain intact.

**OR** do the same but press control (ctrl) and click "Open" or "Open file Location", in the right-click menu, from the file!

Comment: I don't have these options in my context menu.

Answer (score 0):

If your installation of Win 7 doesn't have `open folder location` or `open file location`, here's a solution:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/236988-open-file-location-add-remove-context-menu.html

Here's what's in that solution:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; http://www.sevenforums.com
; Tutorial:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/236988-open-file-location-add-remove-context-menu.html

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryLocation\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Results\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.symlink\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that:

- Right click on the shortcut file name.
- Then use the Open With...  option.
- Select the Windows Media Player option.
- Press the cancel button (so it doesnt run).

It returns to the shortcut folder with that 1 item in the correct form (`C:\Movies\...` rather than `search-ms:displayna...`).

I have to do it for each shortcut item, which is kinda tedious, if I have a lot of them, but it works for me, for now).  I have tried to select several at a time and it only works for 1 of the selection - maybe someone can figure it out for multiple items?

Comment: Please try not to ask your questions in answers: http://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers